# PostgreSQL is not starting on WSL2 launch

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Whenever I restart my WSL2 (using Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows 10) the PostgreSQL service is down. I wanted it to start when my WSL is launched.

```
14/main (port 5432): down
```

I have tried creating a `wsl.conf` in `/etc/wsl.conf`.

Here is the code:

```
# Automatically mount Windows drive when the distribution is launched
[automount]

# Set to true will automount fixed drives (C:/ or D:/) with DrvFs under the root directory set above. Set to false means drives won't be mounted automatically, but need to be mounted manually or with fstab.
enabled = false

# Sets the directory where fixed drives will be automatically mounted. This example changes the mount location, so your C-drive would be /c, rather than the default /mnt/c.
root = /

# Network host settings that enable the DNS server used by WSL 2. This example changes the hostname, sets generateHosts to false, preventing WSL from the default behavior of auto-generating /etc/hosts, and sets generateResolvConf to false, preventing WSL from auto-generating /etc/resolv.conf, so that you can create your own (ie. nameserver 1.1.1.1).
[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true

# Set whether WSL supports interop process like launching Windows apps and adding path variables. Setting these to false will block the launch of Windows processes and block adding $PATH environment variables.
[interop]
enabled = false
appendWindowsPath = false

# Set a command to run when a new WSL instance launches. This example starts the Docker container service.
[boot]
command = service postgresql status
```

Comment: You probably want to start it there, not ask for its status?

Comment: Would probably be easier to use docker windows.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i have to manually start it every time is there a way to start it on boot